# Submit button won't line up vertically with other fields on the same line

Tags: html, css

Can anybody shed some light on why this submit button won't line up vertically with the other form fields on the line?

http://www.e-fluential.com/offline/castoff/

Comment: its another annoyance of IE, looks fine in FF

Comment: Some words about your message to the customers: It's pretty hard to read it since you use this grungy font which is also rotated. I would come up with a clearer approach since the urge on just clicking away is really big IMO.

Comment: @Lawrence: although the vertical alignment was noticeably off in Chrome as well. HTML form field layout isn’t something that browsers (or indeed operating systems) have settled on.

Comment: @Tim also most of the guidance is an image not text, so won't be picked up by search engines or other devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css style to submit button like this:

.submit{float:right;margin-top:-2px}

and adjust margin-right to your needs then

Answer (score 3):

Does `vertical-align: middle` or `vertical-align: text-bottom` help at all?

I always have a nightmare with vertical alignment of form fields.

Comment: @Lee: you’re most welcome! Upvotes and acceptances are as gratefully received as messages of thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the width of the signup class div

Answer (score 0):

add style="float:left" to the span and two inputs.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Faust i think it is too late for this comment. I lost the context of the issue